# Convert a matrix of type double to image in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

i have problem in converting a matrix of type double to image.iam using imwrite for this but each time, the error is too many input arguments. the matrix has values from 0 to 255 but the type is double. i used imread to open the image, then converted it to binary and then used the command double and tried to convert it back into image. i need the binary form in my fyp and then convert it back to image. how is it possible?
if anyone has a solution, kindly help me out.
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
I = imread('test.jpg');
b = dec2bin(I); % b becomes vector
% some actions with binary vector
du = bin2dec(b);
du = reshape(du,size(I)); % converting vector du to 3d Image array 
imwrite(uint8(du), 'du.jpg'); %save our du to file du.jpg

I = imread('du.jpg'); %test if it saved correctly
imshow(du)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. it really helped. The only thing i changed was the last command.If i use imshow(du), it gives a blank image because du is of type char,so i used                                          G = imread('du.jpg'); 
imshow(G). it gives an accurate image.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`im2double`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/im2double.html) to convert from `uint8` values to `double` values. For the inverse, you can use [`im2uint8`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/im2uint8.html).

Comment: i need to do the reverse, from double to image.

Comment: I modified the answer accordingly.

Comment: I need to convert from a data type to image, not from image to double or unint8. when i read the image using imread, i get the type unint8 but i need to convert back to image from double.

Comment: Ooops, that's quite confusing to understand for me. Could you provide a few lines of sample code in your question?

Comment: info=imfinfo('map.jpg')
I=imread('map.jpg');
 b=dec2bin(I);
 du=double(b);
a=imwrite('du.jpg')
imshow(a)                                                           Now it gives the error too many input arguments at imwrite. my project is audio steganography but i want to embed an image in audio as well.I havent worked with image files, so as a beginner i do not have any idea. I will be be embedding the binary form in my audio file. at the decode end after extraction i need to write the image file back and for that this data conversion is required.

Answer (score 0):

If you use java to call matlab function(java sends byte array as input image), first of all convert matrix to unsigned 8 bit integer:

```
m1 = typecast(arr, 'uint8');
```

After set input as unsigned integer, you can use those pixel values as RGB in the range (0, 255). If you want to use some filter like conv2, you must convert unsigned array to image double precision. that can be so:

```
m2 = im2double(m1);
```

Applying convolution generates an output as double precision(between 0-1). After that point, if you want to get unsigned values, you must use that:

```
m3 = im2uint8(m2);
```

Specially when you call matlab from java, typecasting input array to uint8 is very crucial, because matlab receives java byte array as signed int initially. Solving that was very painful, so tracking that conversion steps may be helpful!